# isPalindrome error (cannot find symbol)

Tags: java, compiler-errors, cannot-find-symbol

I'm trying to make a program that will use stacks and queues to check if words are palindromes.

This is my program so far

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class isPalindrome {


    public static boolean isPal(String str){

        QueueArrayBased queue = new QueueArrayBased();
        StackArrayBased stack = new StackArrayBased();
        for (int i = 0; i<=str.length(); i++){
            queue.enqueue(i);
            stack.push(i);
        }

        while (queue.isEmpty != 0){
            if (queue.dequeue() != stack.pop())
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


    public static void main (String [] args){
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Type Word: ");
        String str = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Word: " + str);

        System.out.println(isPal(str));
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error when I compile saying:

```
"isPalindrome.java:16: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable isEmpty
location: class QueueArrayBased
        while (queue.isEmpty != 0)"
```

Here's the isEmpty method that it's giving me an error on

```
public boolean isEmpty()
  {
    return count == 0;
  }  // end isEmpty
```

I'm new to Java and I don't really know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Hint: the compiler thinks it is looking for a *variable* (as opposed to a method or class eg.), which is not the case.

Answer (score 4):

You are calling a method, so it should be `queue.isEmpty() != 0`.

When you do `queue.isEmpty`, the compiler looks for the variable `isEmpty` in `queue`. Since the variable does not exist, it throws the error.